# Cannot get to GRUB2 bootloader or Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7, vaio, easybcd

OK, so I wanted to dual boot Ubuntu 13.10 64bit with Windows 7 64bit on my Sony VAIO laptop. I installed Ubuntu to a separate partition (`/dev/sda6`) and placed the boot loader with Ubuntu on `/dev/sda6`. I rebooted and was taken straight back to windows. It was expected, and I used EasyBCD 2.2 to edit my boot menu and add a GRUB2 (automatically locate and load) to the menu. I rebooted and when I selected it, I got a message saying "Windows Failed to Load". I retried EasyBCD, trying different possibilities like selecting partition 6 instead of the automatic option. It did not work. I re-installed Ubuntu and put the boot loader in `/dev/sda` instead. I rebooted and I found myself, again, at the windows bootloader. I used EasyBCD to no avail. I re-installed Ubuntu again with the boot loader back in `/dev/sda6` and re-did EasyBCD, and again, failure. The error code was `0xc0000098`. I looked through the partitions that were already set up on my system and I found 6:

- `/dev/sda1` - fat32 - SONYSYS - hidden
- `/dev/sda2` - ntfs - Recovery - hidden, diag
- `/dev/sda3` - fat32 - [no label] - boot
- `/dev/sda4` - unknown - [no label] - msftres
- `/dev/sda5` - ntfs - [no label] - msftdata
- `/dev/sda6` - ext4 - [no label, ubuntu 13.10 install] - [no flag]

What should I do? Can I please have detailed, specific instructions, because all answers I found did not work for my scenario.

Edit: in case I was unclear, the fail to load error is for Ubuntu, I can still use windows fine.

Comment: You are showing standard UEFI partitioning for Windows. The sda3 FAT32 partition is the efi partition where UEFI installs place boot files. You do not need EasyBCD. But you have to install Ubuntu in UEFI mode not BIOS mode. How you boot installer is how it installs. http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system and: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: But what should I use for the "Device for boot loader installation"? Edit: and I can't mount the EFI partition to /boot/efi like the UEFI page says. However, it is used as the "EFI Boot partition", which appears to be automatic, so it must have done that all the other times, also.

Comment: You still choose the drive like sda for bootloader install. With UEFI it knows to install to the efi partition or if BIOS install it does install to the MBR of sda. With UEFI the grub install to an efi partition adds the entry to fstab automatically.

Comment: I did that and it booted into the windows boot loader after installing. Should I choose /dev/sda3 for the boot loader instead and try again?

Comment: Should I do that? I really want to get Ubuntu working.

Comment: From UEFI menu choose the ubuntu entry. You should also be able to set it as first, although Windows sometimes resets it so Windows is first in booting. You should also have a one time boot key some systems use f12, and choose which system to boot.

Comment: I don't see anything in the UEFI menu that lets me pick alternate OSs, only boot devices and other system/boot options.

Comment: If you have secure boot on only secure boot systems will be shown. Do you have secure boot back on?

Comment: I believe it is on.

Comment: Turn it off? Or reinstall Ubuntu in secure boot mode.

Comment: How would I install it in secure boot mode?

Comment: See very first comment. How you boot installer is how it installs. So boot Ubuntu installer in UEFI mode with secure boot on. Do not use any auto install options as it may overwrite Windows if Windows not shown or it says only Ubuntu. Use Something else and choose same root as / for new install. Boot-Repair can also convert to secure boot, if you boot it in secure boot mode. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1):

You need to *repair* your windows bootloader and then make grub2 as default bootloader.To do that follow the below steps,

- Boot *windows installation disk* then select the "*windows repair*" or "*repair your computer*" option before you go into the installation process.
- After selecting windows repair option,it will take you to the next screen.In that screen select the "command prompt" option
- Then run the below commands,on it.

  ```
  bootrec /fixmbr
  bootrec /fixboot
  bootrec /rebuildbcd
  ```
- This will repair your windows bootloader.
- Atlast boot [*boot-repair-disk*](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) and click on the *recommended repair* option.Now it works.

Comment: Would a flash drive that was used to make a recovery disk suffice as a windows installation disk?

Comment: Did you want to recover datas?

Comment: I have no issues with Windows nor any issues booting into Windows. I just can't boot into Ubuntu, and therefor Ubuntu has no data that has any worth.

Comment: then run boot-repair,it will reinstall your grub.

Comment: Recommended mode or advanced? Will recommended mode work with UEFI?

Comment: try recommended mode.